AWS ECS: "Exit code: - CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume ''
When create a new service in cluster, task failed to start with error: "Exit code: -
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '': Post "http://plugin.moby.localhost/VolumeDriver.Mount": context deadline exceeded".
My seetings:

Security group for EFS has inbound rule for NFS 2049 port
EFS in the same vpc with cluster


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
